# Проверить соединение с Интернетом

Tags: сеть, delphi

Нужно проверить соединение с интернетом через `Delphi`.
Знаю способ через командную строку и через функцию `InternetGetConnectedState`,
но первый способ медлительный а второй не всегда правдив.
Возможно,вы,знаете какой-либо способ проверки соединения на `Delphi`?

Был вариант, что, создать и проверять подключение `idSMTP`, но, это лишние ресурсы программы, да и почту могут заблокировать за частые проверки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

какова цель проверки? То, что какой то сайт пингуется, ещё не значит, что есть возможность получить какую-то страницу. Майкрософтовкая `InternetGetConnectedState` проверяет просто наличие файла на сайтах майкрософта (где то читал).

Мое предложение - проверяйте возможность получения целевой страницы с целевого сайта - это и будет проверкой.

Помню историю местного провайдера, которому звонили сотни пользователей и жаловались, что у них нет интернета второй день, что они подадут в суд и тому подобное. А все было в том, что лежал вконтакт. Объяснить людям, что вконтакт - это не весь интернет и лежание одного сайта ещё не значит, что нет интернета, их не удовлетворяла. Поэтому, для таких пользователей все программы будут показывать, что интернет есть, но они будут утверждать обратное.

Comment: если ddos'ить get'ами сайт два раза в секунду, то история про вконтакт очень быстро станет реальностью. ping 8.8.8.8 будет более полезной проверкой.

Comment: > если ddos'ить get'ами сайт два раза в секунду

Зачем так часто?

Comment: @Nofate это из предыдущего вопроса ТС.